# Is there any way to ask popup permission at first login?

Tags: javascript, popup

In my project, pop-ups are a core part of the system. Is there any way to ask the user to allow pop-ups on the site at first login, as it happens for HTML 5 Notifications?

EDIT: I know pop-ups are a usually a bad practice, but our customer asked us to implement them for a good reason

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Are you talking about popup windows or just a normal HTML popup/modal thing?

Comment: I'm talking about popup windows in a new browser instance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a url fragment appended to the end of the login redirect url (if when you login it redirects to `/home` you could make your login route redirect to `/home#something_here` instead), and have some javascript in your front end to detect when a page is loaded with that fragment and display the popup.

Also, if your popup is just HTML, you could conditionally render it only when rendering the login success page.

Comment: The real issue is that the "popup blocked" notification is kinda hidden in the address bar. I would like to have something more explicit to allow the user to easily allow pop-ups

Comment: You can use the technique in the answer I gave to show any kind of information when the user logs in, instead of triggering the popup there just display a message to allow it and then trigger the popup on user action.